# Proxy React requests to Flask app using Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, reverse-proxy

I have created a Docker container with a react app and a flask app. As of now, I am getting the error: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /backend_endpoint from localhost:3000 to http://api:5000.` In my `package.json`, I have the line `"proxy": "http://api:5000"`. I read on another post that you are supposed to rename `localhost:5000` to `container_name:5000` in `package.json`, which is why I have `"proxy": "http://api:5000",`. I would appreciate any advice/insight! thank you. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

````
updated docker-compose.yml
```version: '3.7'
services:
   client:
      build:
         context: ./react-app
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      tty: true
      ports:
         - "3000:3000"
      volumes:
         - ./react-app:/app
         - /app/node_modules

   api:
      build:
         context: ./react-app/api
         dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
         - "5000:5000"```
````

Error message:`Proxy error: Could not proxy request /user_entry from localhost:3000 to http://api:5000. See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).`

Comment: If nothing else, the `gunicorn --bind` option needs to be set to `0.0.0.0`, not `127.0.0.1`, to accept calls of any sort from outside its immediate container.  Do you have a more complete error message?

Comment: I added a full image of the error. I tried changing my command to ```command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 pathways:app ```, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The `client` container is on the `default` network, but the `api` container is on the `frontend` and `backend` networks; that might be why they can't communicate.  Deleting all of the `networks:` blocks will set everything to use the `default` network.  You should also be able to delete `volumes:`, `container_name:`, and the `command:` override to simplify the file further.

Comment: (I cannot copy or click the link in the error message you posted; does your system actually print out a plain-text error message, and if so, can you replace the image with that?)

Comment: I have since updated my ```docker-compose.yml``` per your suggestion, still getting same error :/ @DavidMaze